# Vercosine Intuition

Tags: trigonometry

What geometrically is $1+\cos (x)$, and why name it versed cosine? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Vercosine.html has some definitions of some other related unusual trig functions.

Also, can I just make combinations of these? For instance, what would the function: $archacoverexcosech (x)$ look like (also known as the inverse of half of the versed hyperbolic ex co-secant)?

Comment: Why don't you just plot it? It is exactly what it looks like. Are you interested in what the applications are?

Comment: Since I can't find a definition of archacovercosech, I doubt anything would plot it. If you were to make this, what would it be?

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: If you can write (never mind pronounce) "archacovercosech" with a straight face than you are a better man than I.

Comment: (I was not the downvote, though.)

Comment: I think it's like ark hack over co sech???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia gives a good explanation [in this post.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versine)

Usually the versine (vertical sine) and its counterparts were used in aid to sailing, and also to approximate small angles with tables.  The graphs you are looking for are towards the bottom of the page, but the graph for $1+\cos \theta$ is the cosine function translated one unit to the right.

You could make combinations of these...but $\text {archacovercosech}(x)$ (arc-ha-cover-coach-x?) would be a very interesting graph!

Comment: The link goes to versine/. Under the talk section someone asks about verf(x) in general as 2(f(x/2))^2. Wouldn't this be unique to sine and cosine?

Comment: Sorry about that!  I've corrected the link above...yes, it looks like most of the versed functions involve half-angle formulas of sine and cosine.